# postpone postback

Tags: android, asp.net, client-side

**[Interface description]**
The story is about checklist. User interface consists of a long table on a page tailored for a mobile screen. There are  three buttons in a each row (checklist record in the DB) . 
[image: interface eaxmple]

The first button, [FIX], marks this DB record as having an issue? that needs to be fixed. It also changes background color of the middle button to yellow.
The second button [With checklist question] marks record in the database as OK and changes background color of it to green.
The last button [NOGO] marks record as forbidden to transit and changes background color of the middle button to red.

**[How it works now]**
Every button makes post-back, button name and row number is determined, DB record is updated, and new page with a particular background color of the initiating button is generated and reloaded.

**[Problem - slow performance on mobile device on 3G]**
Clicking on any button until page settles takes
Firefox Windows 7 - 0.6 seconds (perfect)
Firefox Samsung Galaxy Xcover Android 2.3.6 on WiFi ~ 2 seconds (manageable)
Firefox Samsung Galaxy Xcover Android 2.3.6 on 3G ~ 12 seconds !!! (3G speed to the server was measured with iperf ~2Mbps)

**[Idea]**
As the page during operation is only writing, and not reading any values from DB, it could operate on client side only, pushing the changed data when final [Save the checklist] button is pressed.

**[Question]**
The only thing coming to my mind right now is - the same generated form where instead of post back buttons are using on click java script to change background colors and population hidden field for each record contain new value to save in DB? The, on post, analyses and save everything.

Can you mention other approaches, ideas? Anything smarter than this direct approach?

Janis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the interface from server side to the client side did the trick. I'm now changing colors with javascript and storing values in hidden fields. Data is transferred on Submit, and then the interface responsiveness is not important anymore.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="questionRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="FIX" style="width: 50px; min-height:50px;" onclick="Q<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cRowid")%>.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF00'; document.getElementById(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cRowid")%>).value='FIX';" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input  type="button" 
                            id='Q<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cRowid")%>' 
                            value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cQuestion")%>'
                            style="width: 250px; white-space: normal; min-height:50px; background-color: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cRColor")%>; font-size: large;" 
                            onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#00FF00'; document.getElementById(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cRowid")%>).value='OK';" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="NOGO" style="width: 50px; min-height:50px;" onclick="Q<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cRowid")%>.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000'; document.getElementById(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cRowid")%>).value='NOGO';" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cRowid")%>'  />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn off `ViewState` would be my first recommendation.

After that run YSlow/Fiddler/Firebug/Chrome Tools...etc to see what takes so long on the client-side, if it's the client-side at all.  Profile the back-end as well at the `DataBase` and `Business Layer` level.

Until to identify your bottleneck(s), you can't effective optimize.

One of many people to say this:

> There's no room for "probably" when you're talking about performance.
>   You must always measure performance to know whether your changes
>   helped or hurt your program.

**Code Complete: A Practical Handbook of Software Construction**

[28.2 Introduction to Code Tuning](http://www.stevemcconnell.com/cctune.htm)

Comment: Rick, the same page on the same device works 5 times slower on different connections. On WiFi it's fast, on 3G it's slow. So I'm not suspecting the code, as it isn't diversifying connections. 
Anyway, my question was not about optimizing code, but taking another approach. Any advices?

Comment: How can you have a different approach if you don't know what is slow and why?

Comment: Moving interface tricks from server side to client side did the trick. Now nothing is being send tot he host during manipulations with only on submit. Advice I was seeking for was "skip aoutopostback, deal with javascript, post on submit"